# SQl Optimization: using same column twice with OR in Where clause, leads very poor performance

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-performance, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

I have contact table, which contain `Ids`, `name`, `email`, `delete` and other columns. Have records around 5 Million.

Writing below query, then facing no issues getting results with in limits:

**execution time:** <2 secs.

```
Select row_id 
from contact 
where row_id in (select row_id 
                 from Contact_details 
                 where email in ('abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com'))
```

but when converting this query with OR clause for at-least default selection of 0 row_id it starts taking too long.

**execution time:** >120 sec.

```
Select row_id 
from contact 
where row_id=0 **OR** row_id in (select row_id 
                                 from Contact_details 
                                 where email in ('abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com'))
```

I have tried union rather than using OR, yes that improves performance but this is an application generated query, so is there a way through which this query can be improved without using union or union all.

Comment: What is your question - do you want to understand why it's happening, or get it to run faster?

Comment: How long does "Select row_id from contact where row_id=0" take to execute?

Comment: Please post the execution plan for both queries. Also, informations about table structure, including indexes,  and number of records would be useful

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it in part depends on the time to execute `SELECT row_id  FROM contact WHERE row_id = 0`.  If that's slow, the `OR` isn't too blame.

If it's not slow, an `OR` can often throw a spanner in the Plan being generated *(I'd love to see the full explain plan for all of these queries)*.  In which case, you could try this...

```
SELECT row_id 
  FROM contact 
 WHERE row_id IN (SELECT row_id 
                    FROM contact_details 
                   WHERE email in ('abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com')

                  UNION ALL

                  SELECT 0
                    FROM dual
                 )
```

*(And give us the explain plan to that query as well...)*

***EDIT:***

Wait, are you ***really*** just selecting `row_id`, even in the outer query?  If so, just do this?

```
SELECT row_id 
  FROM contact 
 WHERE row_id IN (SELECT row_id 
                    FROM contact_details 
                   WHERE email in ('abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com')
                 )
UNION
SELECT 0
  FROM dual
```

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie for quick response, I know union can improve the performance, but it is a kind of system generated query for contact segment creation where I want to add 0 contact id if no id is selected.

Comment: Then give us the explain plans to help us identify the reason for the slow performance

Answer (score 0):

sometime you can have performance issues with OR. In this case you can split your query with UNION :

```
Select row_id 
from contact 
where row_id in (select row_id 
                       from Contact_details 
                       where email in ('abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com'))
UNION ALL
Select row_id 
from contact 
where row_id=0;
```

Comment: Care needs to be taken with that suggestion.  First ensuring that a row can't appear in both queries.  Based on what we've been told that seems unlikely, but certainly possible.